# Struts-JQuery Disable drop down option based on a selection of a different drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, drop-down-menu, struts2

In my JSP I have a form with multiple drop down items.  This is a form using the struts-tags declaration.

On this form, I want to disable one or more options of one drop down based on the selection of a separate drop down on the same form.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate.  This is how I have my drop downs coded.

```
<s:select id="vehicleType" name="vehicleType" list="#{'0': 'Truck','1':'Sedan'}"

<s:select id="vehicleList" name="vehicleList" list="#{'0':'Ford F150','1':'Dodge Ram','2':'Honda Accord','3':'Nissan Altima'}"
```

If I select "Truck" from the "vehicleType" drop down, I want to disable both "Honda Accord" and "Nissan Altima" from the "vehicleList" drop down.  If I select "Sedan" from the "vehicleType" drop down, I want to disable both "Ford F150" and "Nissan Altima" from the "vehicleList" drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code to disable the options:

```
$("#vehicleType").on('change', function() {
    var vlist = $("#vehicleList");
    vlist.find('option').prop('disabled', false);

    if (this.value === "0") {
        vlist.find('option[value="2"]').prop('disabled', true);
        vlist.find('option[value="3"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else if (this.value === "1") {
        vlist.find('option[value="0"]').prop('disabled', true);
        vlist.find('option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mfd13w6u/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function resetVehicleList(vehicleType)
{
    $('#vehicleList option').show();
    if($(vehicleType).val() == '0')
    {
        $('#vehicleList option[value="2"]').hide();
        $('#vehicleList option[value="3"]').hide();
    }
    else if($(vehicleType).val() == '1')
    {
        $('#vehicleList option[value="0"]').hide();
        $('#vehicleList option[value="1"]').hide();
    }
    $('#vehicleList').val($('#vehicleList option:visible').first().attr('value'));
}

$('#vehicleType').change(function(){
    resetVehicleList(this);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    resetVehicleList($('#vehicleType'));
});
```